# Focusing on element when bottomsheet is displayed on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**[Problem]**

I have a HTML Input element to focus on inside my bottomsheet which is hidden by default. I would like to focus on it when bottomsheet is shown, but I am keep missing it.

**[What I've tried]**

1. I already tried `autoFocus={true}` but it didn't work.
2. I tried the following, still not working.

```
const bottomSheetPage = (props) => {
  const [bottomSheetOn, setBottomSheetOn] = useState(false)
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

~~~ some codes ~~~

  useEffect ( () => {
    if(props.autoFocus) {
      inputRef?.current?.focus()
    }
  }, [isBottomsheetOn])

~~~ some codes ~~~
  
    <input ref={inputRef}/>
```

`bottomSheetOn` is state that controls the toggle of bottomsheet and checked that `prop.autoFocus === true`.

How can I focus on the element inside bottomsheet when it's shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several ways to fix this up, and there was two methods I've actually tried. Either with different advantages.

1. using `IntersectionObserver` and `setTimeout`

you can check if one element intesects other by `IntersectionObserver.observe()` so I made a recrurring function to check intersection, and then set focus when it's intersecting. Codes is as follows.

```
const [ticker, setTicker] = useState(true)
const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false)

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting))

useEffect(() => {
  if(props.autoFocus) {
    if(inputRef?.current) {
      if (isIntersecting) {
        inputRef.current.focus()
      } else {
        setTimerout(() => setTicker(!ticker), 500)
      }
    }
  }
  return () => {observer.disconnect()}
}, [ticker])
```

But this method was focusing on element only once. I needed to focus on it everytime it's shown.

2. using `setTimeout`

I figured out that problem was there's time needed for rendering toggled bottomsheet, so I simply gave timeout for focus. And it worked out.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (focusRef?.current) {
    setTimeout(setFocus, 1000)
  }
})

const setFocus = () => {
  if (focusRef?.current){
    focusReft.focus()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could have one of two reasons:

1. props.autoFocus is false
2. props.autoFocus is true, but useEffect is only called when isBottomsheetOn changes

Try adding props.autoFocus to the list of useEffect dependencies and console.log/debugger inside useEffect to make sure it is called correctly.

```
useEffect ( () => {
    if(props.autoFocus) {
      inputRef?.current?.focus()
    }
  }, [isBottomsheetOn, props.autoFocus]) // will be triggered on props.autoFocus change
```

If that doesn't help, try to set the focus manually to make sure it's not a problem with the input ref.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Component(props) {
      const inputRef = useRef(null)
      const [on, setOn] = useState(true)
    
      useEffect ( () => {
          if (on) {
            inputRef?.current?.focus()
          }
      }, [on])
    
    return (
      <>
        <input ref={inputRef}/>
        <button onClick={() => setOn(prev => !prev)}>Focus</button>
      </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just tested it with your code, adding `on` on useEffect, and clicking on it just works fine as expected. but still the focus is not working when bottomsheet is shown.

Comment: What do you mean "bottomsheet is shown"? Is it about change of state or the first render of component?

Comment: It is about when it is visible, because my bottomsheet is invisible for default like `<div visible={isBottomsheetOn}>`. I wanted to know if there was any hooks I can use to detect the visibility change of element.